Python Package 'ntscraper' Not Returning Anything
!pip install ntscraper

from ntscraper import Nitter
from pprint import pprint

scraper = Nitter()

tweets = scraper.get_tweets("AAPL", "term", 1000)

pprint(tweets)

INFO:root:No instance specified, using random instance ``https://nitter.privacydev.net
WARNING:root:Empty page on ``https://nitter.privacydev.net
{'threads': [], 'tweets': []}
Any idea why when using this simple twitter scrapping function from 'ntscraper' the return is empty?
Thanks for the help.
get_tweets arguments are: Query, Term/Hastag/User, Size.
I've tried different arguments and always got empty returns.

From the ntscraper project homepage: "Twitter has recently made some changes which affected every third party Twitter client, including Nitter. As a result, most Nitter instances have shut down or will shut down shortly. Even local instances are affected by this, so you may not be able to scrape as many tweets as expected, if at all."
